# Issues with converting Eclipse Groovy project to Gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have an existing Groovy project, created with the Eclipse IDE, defined to be:

```
SposZohoMergeScript
  -- src
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.constants
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.factories
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.io
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.mergers
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.models
    -- com.xxx.sposZohoMergeScript.utils
```

I have been *manually* downloading, vetting, and bringing into the project build path the individual JAR files per each library and dependency... Not to mention there's no built-in system for testing... How am I supposed to keep working like this?!

It's time to bring in Gradle!

I try the Gradle plugin, and it goes sideways pretty much immediately...

I run the build setup init step, and it runs forever...even if I go to sleep, wake up a few hours later, and check back on it, it's still there...

I close the Eclipse IDE, open up the BASH, on the SposZohoMergeScript folder, run `gradle init` myself, and it re-fucktors my project.

I try to set it up as basic project:

[image]

I then create the `build.gradle`:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This is a general purpose Gradle build.
 * Learn more about Gradle by exploring our samples at https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/samples
 */
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'

}
```

I then do a `gradle build`, which runs successfully. After that, I open up the Eclipse, and not only do I see my folder structure all messed up...

[image]

but when I go to, for example, use the keyboard shortcuts to create a constructor, it gives me error, and the highlighter/IntelliSense can't make sense of previously-working code I have written:

[image]

I run `gradle dependencies` for the project, and this is what I get:

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'SposZohoMergeScript'
------------------------------------------------------------

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
|    +--- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
\--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (*)
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3
     |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1
     |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     +--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1 (*)
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
     +--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.07
     +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     \--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (n)
\--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3 (n)

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
|    +--- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
\--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (*)
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3
     |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1
     |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     +--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1 (*)
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
     +--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.07
     +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     \--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
|    +--- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
\--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (*)
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3
     |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1
     |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     +--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1 (*)
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
     +--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.07
     +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     \--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3
|    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
|    +--- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
\--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (*)
     +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.3
     |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1
     |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     +--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.1.1 (*)
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
     +--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.07
     +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0
     \--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I am using Eclipse IDE Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0), Build id: 20220908-1902 , and Gradle 7.2, on Windows 10 64-bit computer .

What can I do to get Gradle working with the Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by, "the Gradle plugin"?

Comment: The Gradle plugin for Eclipse

Comment: Does right-clicking the project and choosing _Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project_ help (since you have done something outside of Eclipse)?

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot alone, the directory structure is not correct for Gradle.

By convention, the Java and Groovy plugin configure their source sets to be `src/main/java` and `src/main/groovy`:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#sec:groovy_project_layout

Your screenshot shows that you only have `src/` followed by your code/package. Move your code to be under `src/main/groovy/` for Groovy code and `src/main/java` for Java code.

To correct your project structure in Eclipse do the following:

1. **Right-click** the **project** and choose ***New > Folder*** and create the folder **`src/main/java`**
2. **Move** the folder **`src/com` into `src/main/java`**
3. **Right-click `src/main/java`** and choose ***Build Path > Use As Source Folder***